# A "less...more" usage

Tags: meaning-in-context

"The less I prayed, the spirits would appear to me more."

Could this sentence, although not formally correct, make any sense at all, in the context of song lyrics ?

Comment: 'The less X happened, the more Y happened' is standard. So 'The less I prayed, the more the spirits would appear to me.' But song lyrics rarely conform to normal standards. What you suggest seems pretty transparent, but is that the only requirement?

Comment: If you can't use your creativity within lyrics and poetry to break a few rules, when can you? Besides, words that are silly on the page have worked well with the right music supporting the meaning, ooh baby baby ooh baby.

Comment: Of course!  Does *Moon River* 'make sense'?

Comment: By itself, that phrase fails to the extent it doesn't match up to Edwin's *The less X happened, the more Y happened*.

It could work very well in a song lyric, but only further context would tell… a little like *Moon River* which is meaningless by itself but not in context.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comment. The thing is that I have doubts, more than I’d like to admit, on whether one should transgress grammar rather than pursuit beauty

Comment: I found it jarring.  Parallelism isn't just a feature of prose, but also of poetry, maybe more so.  I'd find it beautiful if all of it is beautiful, including the grammar.

Comment: *Less is more* has a wiki article...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_is_more which mentions a Robert Browning poem, the famous architectural phrase by Mies van der Rohe (after Adolph Loos) and other minimalist usages.

Comment: In the context of song lyrics, as long as you have most of the words in the approximately right order, people will forgive you and understand your meaning. Provided that the song sounds good the way it's written, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is understandable to us.

An underlying question seems to be about **poetic license** with grammar:

> The liberty taken by an artist or a writer in deviating from
>   conventional form or fact to achieve a desired effect
>   ([American Heritage](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=poetic%20license))

My reaction would be: pursue beauty, since that's what **poetry** is about! It is often acceptable to change the common order of words in poetry (quite in addition to spelling), as it is different from common prose.

Moreover, *[de gustibus non disputandum](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/de_gustibus_non_est_disputandum#Latin)* (there is no arguing about tastes)... I understand that the theme would be religious, but it depends also on the style of music adopted (e.g. spirituals have had a lot of freedom), and what the audience is already used to, etc.

I would nevertheless be prepared to draw criticism from eminently rational people, but that goes along with *poetry*, which [Webster also defined as](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/poetry):

> the language of excited imagination and feeling.